# Android WebView Exception

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

[image: normal webview]

[image: webview exception]

I am using `WebView` in android. When I click one of the three buttons, it renders a related website in the rest of the screen. When I click the first button, it works well (picture 1)(http://www.baidu.com). But when I click the rest of two, it pops out a hint to let me choose the browser(picture 2). Why it can not be rendered as the first one?

My `activity.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".WebsiteSwitcher"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TableRow>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_one"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Baidu"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_two"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Weibo"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_three"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Renren"/>
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

And my codes in `onCreate` method like this：

```
Button goBaidu = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_one);
    goBaidu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.loadUrl("http://www.baidu.com");
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it pops out a hint to let me choose the browser(picture 2). Why it can
>   not be rendered as the first one?

To load other pages from links clicked on web page inside WebView set `WebViewClient` by Overriding `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` :

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: @Liquid: Very good explanation is provided in api [shouldOverrideUrlLoading](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) method description

Comment: @Liquid: if still need explanation then i will answer your questions.thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to just set WebViewClient:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

The doc says *"If WebViewClient **is not provided**, by default WebView will ask Activity Manager to choose the proper handler for the url"*. Once you provide it, even the default one, WebView already starts loading URLs in itself.

In fact, calling `view.loadUrl(url)` and returning `true` from `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` is not the best thing to do, as `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` is also called for subframes with non-https schemes (e.g. `tel:`).